# Updating data from one function to another

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts JS to generate charts on my website and I've ran into a problem not being able to update data from a different functioning.

Here's the example code:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(test);

function test() {
    chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart.addColumn('string', 'Lorem');
    chart.addColumn('number', 'Ipsum');
    chart.addRows([
            ['', 0]
    ]);
        var chartOptions = {};
    var chartCreate = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
          chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
    ]);
}

function test2() {
    chart.addRows([
        ['Uno', 123],
        ['Dos', 233],
        ['Tres', 12],
        ['Quatro', 231]
    ]);
    chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
}

setTimeout(test2(),5000)
```

As you can see, I will have new data in the test2 function every 5 seconds which I need to populate the Google Chart in function test.  The reason I don't want to put the whole test function into test2 function is because it would start a new instance of the chart every 5 seconds and that was somewhat of a memory hog as memory just kept on increasing.

It would be great if there was a way to just add new rows to the chart, but according to Google's documentation, the only way to add rows is to redraw the chart each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
setTimeout(test2, 5000)
```

The first argument to `setTimeout` is a function. You were *calling* the function and passing its result (which is `undefined`, because `test2()` doesn't return anything) to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes a function reference. In your call, you're invoking the function with the ().  You want to pass only the name of the function so that setTimeout can invoke it at a later time (5 seconds from now) like this:

```
setTimeout(test2, 5000)
```

INSIDE of the function test. This will make sure that the timer isn't set before the initial call is loaded.

Also, make sure to give the chart variable in the first function the "var" keyword, otherwise you'll create a global variable (unless that was intended.)

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(test);

function test() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart.addColumn('string', 'Lorem');
    chart.addColumn('number', 'Ipsum');
    chart.addRows([['', 0]]);
    var chartOptions = {};
    var chartCreate = new         

    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
    chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
    setTimeout(test2,5000)
}

function test2() {
    chart.addRows([
        ['Uno', 123],
        ['Dos', 233],
        ['Tres', 12],
        ['Quatro', 231]
    ]);
    chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into scope issues with that, as that method requires global variables.  You can avoid problems with globals by wrapping everything in one function:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(test);

function test() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart.addColumn('string', 'Lorem');
    chart.addColumn('number', 'Ipsum');
    chart.addRows([
        ['', 0]
    ]);
    var chartOptions = {};
    var chartCreate = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
    chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);

    function test2() {
        chart.addRows([
            ['Uno', 123],
            ['Dos', 233],
            ['Tres', 12],
            ['Quatro', 231]
        ]);
        chartCreate.draw(chart, chartOptions);
    }

    setTimeout(test2, 5000);
}
```

`setTimeout` will call `test2` after 5 seconds, but not every 5 seconds.  If you want to repeat every 5 seconds, you can either call `setTimeout(test2, 5000);` at the end of the `test2` function, or you can use `setInterval(test2, 5000);` instead.